# How to constrain b2Bodys' linear velocity angle

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I want to force the linear velocity direction of a b2Body to be within certain bounds.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way of doing it is to set it manually. Like this:

```
// pseudo code
velocity = body.GetLinearVelocity();

if(velocity > maxVelocity)
  velocity = maxVelocity;

body.SetLinearVelocity(velocity);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the magnitude but I would like to ensure the direction / angle is within certain bounds